# Geometric question on finding the length of the tangent

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

Consider a circle $ C $ with radius $ r $ and a point $P $ outside the circle. Construct two tangents from  $P$  to the circle, touching the circle at points $ A $ and $ B $. Let $ O $ be the center of the circle.

Question: If $ OP = 2r $ , find the exact length of the tangent segment $ PA $ (from point $ P $ to point $A $.

My approach:
Now, let me give this problem a try.

Given that the area of triangle OAB is $3r^2$ and OP is twice the length of the radius $2r$, I need to determine the length of the tangent segment PA.

First, I denoted the length of PA as $x$. Since triangle $OAB$ is isosceles, we know that $OA = OB$.

Using the Pythagorean theorem, I  expressed OB in terms of r:
$OB^2$ = $OP^2$ - $BP^2$
$OB^2$ = $2r^2$ - $r^2$
$OB^2$ = $4r^2$ - $r^2$
$OB^2$ = $3r^2$

Next, I find the area of triangle OAB:
$[Area_{OAB} = \frac{1}{2} \times PA \times OB]$
$[3r^2 = \frac{1}{2} \times x \times \sqrt{3r^2}]$

Solving for $(x)$:
$[6r^2 = x \times r \sqrt{3}]$
$[x = \frac{6r^2}{r \sqrt{3}}]$
$[x = \frac{6r}{\sqrt{3}}]$ after rationalizing
$[x = 2r \sqrt{3}]$

So, according to my calculations, the length of the tangent segment PA is $2r \sqrt{3}$. This seems like a plausible solution, but but it seems that the correct answer to this question is $3r$. Where did I go wrong and how can we arrive at the correct answer

Comment: $A,B$ are points on the circle, so $OA=OB=r$. Now the area of $\Delta OAB$ is given by $\dfrac{1}{2}OA\times OB\times\sin\angle OAB=0.5r^2\sin\theta=3r^2$. But isn't this means $\sin\theta=6$?

Comment: The value of the sign function cannot exceed one this is definitely an error

Comment: According to the Pythagorean theorem in $OAP,AP^2=OP^2-OA^2=4r^2-r^2=3r^2$

Comment: @AngaeMT : the area of $OAB$ is given by $\frac12OA\times OB\times \sin(\widehat{AOB})$. Isn't it ?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen thanks for your clarification. But my point is the question itself may already have some contradict information, as the answer below mentioned, some info is redundant, making the question itself may not solvable

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather odd question. Since we know that $PA$ is tangent to the circle we immediately know that $OA$ is a radius. Of course, this means it has length $r$, and also that $PAO$ is a right-angle. Additionally, you state that $OP$ has length $2r$. This trivially allows the Pythagorean theorem to be used to solve for $x$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
r^2 + x^2 & = (2r)^2 \\
r^2 + x^2 & = 4r^2 \\
x^2 & = 3r^2 \\
x & = \sqrt{3} r
\end{aligned}
$$

The area information is not used. I didn't check if it is consistent with everything else. It may just be a misdirect, or the problem may be overspecified in some incorrect way, but you can check this easily enough yourself.